How do I make a classifier that's robust to variation in data imbalance?
I'm writing a binary classifier for data that is often pretty unbalanced, e.g. 99% in the majority class (using gradient boosting), but I'd like to have a classifier that is at least somewhat robust to how severe the imbalance is. The imbalance ratio varies a lot between one data set and another. Class A fraction may be >99% or as low as 75%. Ideally I'd like to train my classifier on a single training set, then have it perform reasonably well on test sets with pretty different class frequencies. Are there any established ways to do this? Or will I just need to retrain the model for each new data set according to the expected degree of imbalance?

There's a way to adjust predictions when you want to operate in a situation where the overall class ratio differs from the overall class ratio of the training data. This could be what you want.

Optimizing AUC or generally controlling separately FPR and TPR, rather than just accuracy or its equivalent.

In my view, outside the fields of domain adaptation and covariate shift correction, this problem is not extensively covered, but there are a few things to work through thought. (The comment from Dave (+1) correctly mentions adjusting for prior probabilities explicitly, so I won't cover it here more, that is reasonable starting point but omits some nuisances I cover below)
There are two main points here:

We need to train a well-calibrated classifier. (i.e. if our classifier predicts that a subset of our sample has approximate probability 0.7 to be of class $A$, in that subset we should indeed have approximately 70% of the instances actually belonging to class $A$) Calibration is crucial when dealing with shifting class imbalances because the raw output scores might not be comparable across datasets with different class priors. If these probabilities are off, any adjustment is moot.
We need to clarify what is the cause of the change in base frequencies. Going from 1% prevalence to 25% is not a minor change, but rather suggests a domain shift (change in the underlying data distribution) and/or covariate drift. Yes, there are adaption steps for over/under-sampling that can be done, but those are for training purposes only. In this case, where we are referring to "test sets with pretty different class frequencies" there is more afoot than just an imbalanced learning issue (if that is really an issue anyway).

OK, and some additional points/complementary ways forward: There is a slightly niche research field called "Domain-invariant feature learning". It is effectively an off-shoot of "domain adversarial training" to learn features that are invariant across different class distributions. I am not well-versed on it, but it is an option to consider, look at the concept of maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) for starters as a potential cost function (e.g. see Training generative neural networks via maximum mean discrepancy optimization (2015) Dziugaite by et al. for an early implementation of this).
In that respect, "Covariate shift correction" was recognised pretty early on too (e.g. Covariate Shift by Kernel Mean Matching (2007)) but never took off afterwards. Worth checking though...
A more applicable option is to use cost-sensitive learning. Are all the misclassifications equally damaging? That is something to consider. Probably this opens up the discussion if these costs should be static or not. There are heaps of papers on this subject, though Elkan's 2001: The Foundations of Cost-Sensitive Learning is probably one of the most well-cited papers on the matter, so it is a very decent start. Cost-sensitive learning as a whole is very good because it forces us to think about our exact problem.
Finally, (mostly because of the ask "will I just need to retrain the model for each new data") we could consider transfer learning in the sense of having a main classifier as a starting point (i.e. a pretrained model) and then and fine-tune them on each new dataset. This is not as hard as it sounds, for example we can have gradient booster aleady trained with $k$ learners on our pooled sample up to time-point $t$ and then add $l$ learners training on the new dataset we received at time $t$. Most modern libraries (e.g. xgboost, lightgbm, catboost) have relevant functionality, Boosting for transfer learning (2007) by Dai et al. is a very relevant paper on this.
So to recap: Ensure the classifier's predictions are well-calibrated and investigate in more detail why there are such large fluctuations in the underlying prevalence rate. Then look into more targeted actions accordinly.

As @Dave mentions in the comments, you can adjust the output of a probabilistic classifier (that provides estimates of the posterior probability of class membership) if the prior class probabilities are different in operational use than in the training set.  It is also possible to use an EM-based approach to estimate the priors and adjust the outputs on the fly in operation, which may be useful if the priors change over time:
Saerens, M., Latinne, P., & Decaestecker, C. (2002). Adjusting the outputs of a classifier to new a priori probabilities: a simple procedure. Neural computation, 14(1), 21-41. (doi:10.1162/089976602753284446, pdf)
I have used this in a couple of projects and found it to work well.  You will probably need a classifier with reasonably well calibrated probability estimates (e.g. [kernel] logistic regression, Gaussian process classifiers etc.), it may not work so well with Naive Bayes or DNN without additional recalibration.

+1 by me, but I do think this really hides under the carpet the point about why the change in prevalence happens. Even in the paper linked, the training set is 50-50 and then the tests prevalences between 10% and 90% taken from the same sample. Here we are talking going to potentially <1% apparently to 25% prevalence, so this is almost akin to changing the task (an anomaly detection vs. classification situation) or a full distribution shift (i.e. change of domain).

@usεr11852 there are tasks where the prevalence does drift/change over time, in one of the applications I am interested in I am using the EM approach to track and model the change in prevalence as that is the  feature of the data the scientists are interested in.  It isn't changing the task though if the likelihood, $p(x|C)$, for each class remains the same (which should be the case for my application).
